# Query Related to using a function of oracle in windows and unix platform

Tags: mysql

If I am executing the query with chr(10) in oracle in windows platform its working fine, but when the same query is executed in unix platform its not working. Please Help.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Windows and Unix doesnt have the same carrier return left that Unix. In Windows it's (13)+(10) or (10)+(13), while in unix there's only (10)
That's the difference between /n and /n/r